# Unity3d - Reflections do not update when changing Skybox color

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader, skybox

When my game first loads the objects in the scene are reflecting the color of the Skybox.

Which is good.

But then when I change the Skybox material's color, there is no effect on the reflection and the objects remain the same color.

Is there any way I can fix this?

Unity3D LWRP

Comment: if your gameobject's material depends on the skybox reflection then it will change otherwise it will not change. lighting will not be effected by skybox

Comment: The problem is that the reflections are not changing.

Comment: Are you using baked reflection probes? And could you maybe add some screenshots that show us the problem?

Comment: I am currently not using reflection probes.  Is a reflection probe necessary?

Comment: Which shader are you using on that objects? Maybe your shader has the skybox material as a field, then you must assign the new skybox to all the shaders when you change the main one... Screenshots will help :P